# zombie.js browser.fire not working with Backbone.Events

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, zombie.js

The browser.fire method does not seem to trigger event handlers attached through Backbone.Events. (it works fine for other cases such as clicking anchor tags/buttons)

See this gist for a test case on documentClouds site:
https://gist.github.com/1256944

If the first thing you do when going to the url is click the 'Open' button you get an alert, but also the 'overlay' class is added to the body element - this is what im checking for.

You can see from the test that when using browser.fire 'click', that the prompt isn't shown, and the overlay class is not seen.

However, when triggering the click event using jQuery's click() method (via browser.evaluate), then the overlay class is seen...

Comment: Define "event handlers attached through Backbone.Events".

Comment: e.g. "click .somediv": "onClick" which is usually placed in the view

Comment: Can you include the html view associated with this Backbone view.  Usually the problem with events in backbone is that the target class doesn't exist in the DOM. If #open_viewers isn't inside of #toolbar, it won't work.

Comment: Nope it wasn't something as simple as that unfortunately. I moved off zombie a while back because of this bug and others that kept cropping up. I posted this issue on the projects github back then, and other people have reported having the same problem: https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/181

Answer (score 0):

In your backbone view, you should add the el property. Specify an element upon which the events should be bound. For example:

```
dc.ui.Toolbar = Backbone.View.extend({

  id : 'toolbar',

  el : "body",

  events : {
    'click #open_viewers' : '_clickOpenViewers',
    'click #size_toggle'  : '_toggleSize'
  },

  _clickOpenViewers : function() {
    this.openViewers();
  },

  openViewers : function(checkEdit, suffix, afterLoad) {
    if (!Documents.selectedCount) return dc.ui.Dialog.alert('Please select a document to open.');
    var continuation = function(docs) {
      _.each(docs, function(doc){
        var win = doc.openAppropriateVersion(suffix);
        if (afterLoad) {
          win.DV || (win.DV = {});
          win.DV.afterLoad = afterLoad;
        }
      });
    };
    checkEdit ? this.edit(continuation) : continuation(Documents.selected());
  }

});
```